# Changing data validation source values does not update cells using the original value

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have `Sheet1` with an in-cell dropdown select box. The values in the drop-down come from the values in a different range (i.e. on `Sheet2`)

What I need now is to update the value in any cells with data validation in `Sheet1` if I change those values in `Sheet2`. Currently, if I update values in my validation range (`Sheet2`), the cells using the old value in `Sheet1` show a warning:

[image: TestRangeValue]

How to mass update past rows with updated range in `Sheet2`?

**UPDATE**:

In other words:

I change a value in my data validation's criteria range, but previously added rows that already selected that value - which was valid at that time - still have the old value. Viewing the drop-down range then flags these previous settings as invalid. Can I somehow update any cells that used the old data validation value to use the new value?

Answer (score 0):

Set the lookup range of the data validation to the whole column instead of a specific range, e.g. `A:A` or `A2:A` instead of `A2:A10`, then you won't have to update the range in the data validation formulas.

Comment: This is true for just the quantity of the values in range. Not the value itself.

Comment: @PeterGeorge the actual selected value will still depend on the user (you) making a selection, so not sure what you mean by mass updating values. Would you like to set the default value for each row?

Comment: @AntonDementiev, no I need to change a value in my range, but previously added rows with a previously select value selected doesn't change.

Comment: Just update the lookup range and then run a [Find and Replace](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/62754?p=spreadsheets_find_replace) on the cells with data validation

Comment: @PeterGeorge They don't change because they are not supposed to. You changed the source range for the Data Validation rule but still need to enter the values manually. What is the expected outcome - would you like the old values to be replaced by blank cells again?

Comment: @Jordan is there some script that recognize my update in data validation for automated behaviour? Or everytime I need to "Find and replace" manually? I need to change it very frequenlty unfortunately.

Comment: @AntonDementiev I need those old cell to change automatically showing the new just updated values in data validation range.

Comment: @PeterGeorge Doesn't Jordan's solution work for you? I tested things on my side - the list values are immediately updated with new items as soon as you add them to Sheet 2.

Comment: There's a new macro recorder function within Google Sheets however it doesn't seem to track any changes made by the Find and Replace function so you'd need to write your own from scratch, perhaps have a pop-up box to input the string to replace and the replacement string, then loop through the rows to replace the strings after replacing the old string for the new one in the data validation range in `Sheet2`.

Comment: @AntonDementiev I dont' need to add or remove, I need to update values in list range of Sheet2 and then I need the original values in Sheet1 to reflect my updates values.

Comment: @Jordan thanks but this is too much complicated because I need integration of Google Scripts.

Comment: How should a script know about the new values? Say, if you have a list of values for Data Validation defined as [a, b, c]  and your selection for Sheet 1 is: Cell1 - c, Cell2 - a, Cell3 - c. If you change the validation list to [x, y, z]  (Sheet2), how would you like to update the 3 cells? There are plenty of options ( Cell1 - x, Cell2 - y, Cell 3 - z, xxx, xyx, etc)

Comment: @PeterGeorge Sorry, I forgot to address the previous comment to you. Could you please clarify the above?

Comment: @AntonDementiev in your exmplae the list become: CAC > ZXZ. What's the strange? This is what I need. I change a value in data vlidation array (Sheet2) and it changes my preovious selected values in Sheet1. This is all I need. How?

Comment: @AntonDementiev Anyway thanks for your positive contribution to the solution.